# How backward relation works with Django query set

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have below models.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
# Create your models here.


class IndustryCat1(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'industry_cat_1'



class IndustryCat2(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    num = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    label = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    industry_cat_1_id = models.ForeignKey('IndustryCat1')

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'industry_cat_2'



class IndustryCat3(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    num = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    label = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    industry_cat_2_id = models.ForeignKey('IndustryCat2', blank=True, null=True, related_name='industry_cat_2_id')

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Industry_cat_3'




class IndustryCat4(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    num = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    label = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    industry_cat_3_id = models.ForeignKey('IndustryCat3', blank=True, null=True, related_name='industry_cat_3_id')

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Industry_cat_4'
```

This is the file where I am writing queries:
industries.py:

```
from demo.models import IndustryCat1, IndustryCat2
import datetime
from django.db.models import Q

class Industries:


    @staticmethod
    def getIndustries(indId):
        try:

            b = IndustryCat1.objects.filter()
            return b.industrycat2_set.all()  # Returns all Entry objects related to Blog.

        except IndustryCat1.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

This is the file where I need to get results returned from query which is implemented in industries.py:
views.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.http import HttpResponse
from models import IndustryCat1
from demo.core.persistence.Industries import *
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render, render_to_response
from django.core import serializers
import json

def index(request):

    industry = Industries()

    qs = industry.getIndustries(1)

    return HttpResponse(serializers.serialize("json", qs))

    context = {'indus': indus}

    return render(request, 'demo/test/industries_catagories.html', context)
```

My table structure is as follows:

IndustryCat1 has results two columns id and name.

IndustryCat2 has industryCat1 id as foreignKey.

I want to fetch all the IndustryCat1 records and their corresponding industryCat2

Which I am trying to do using below query in industries.py:

```
 b = IndustryCat1.objects.filter()
            return b.industryCat2_set.all()
```

But I get below error:

> AttributeError at /demo/ 'QuerySet' object has no attribute
>   'industryCat2_set'

Any help on how I can apply such query will be helpful as I am stuck.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

The default related name should be all in lower case.

```
...
b.industrycat2_set.all() # correct syntax but incorrect usage
```

OTOH, you have a queryset not a single object. You can't access the reverse foreignkey relation directly from the queryset only from each of the objects in the queryset that `filter` returns.

On a final note, do not add `_id` to the field name for your foreign keys. It gets all messy when you actually need to access the `id` of the foreign key field.

Comment: Thanks for your help!.
I am now getting error:
AttributeError at /demo/
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'industrycat2_set'

Comment: In mysql my table name is industry_cat_2.

Comment: @Simer Are you using a `related_name` you're not showing?

Comment: should I add
 industry_cat_1_id = models.ForeignKey('IndustryCat1', related_name='industry_cat_1_id')  to my model. I have deleted related_name to remove the complications.

Comment: You can use `industry_cat_1 = models.ForeignKey('IndustryCat1', related_name='industry_cat_2')` and then `b.industry_cat_2.all()`

Comment: @Simer Not very comfortable with your names tho.

Comment: Sorry name are irksome. I have modified the model as you stated in your comment. But still getting error: AttributeError at /demo/
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'industry_cat_2'. 
Is there any way to do this in raw mysql?

Comment: Try making migrations and migrating first.

Comment: This one query has stuck  me to proceed if you can help then it would be a big favor.

Comment: I have run make migrations and migrate after making changes to model but still get error :
AttributeError at /demo/
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'industry_cat_2'.
Any further help?
Thanks!!

Comment: I didn't notice you were using `filter`. See the update on my answer. Reverse relation can only be accessed from model instances contained in the queryset, and not from the queryset itself

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154977/discussion-between-simer-and-moses-koledoye).